# JavaCv comparison of three and more images

Tags: opencv, image-recognition, javacv

I have tried the cvMatchTemplate function to compare two images(a template and an image).

```
    IplImage img = cvLoadImage("thumbnail.jpg");
    IplImage template = cvLoadImage("temp.jpg");
    IplImage result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img.width()-template.width()+1, img.height()-template.height()+1), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    int method = CV_TM_SQDIFF;
    cvMatchTemplate(img,template,result,method);
    cvShowImage("res",result);

    double[] min_val = new double[2];
    double[] max_val = new double[2];

    //Where are located our max and min correlation points
    CvPoint minLoc = new CvPoint(); 
    CvPoint maxLoc = new CvPoint();

    cvMinMaxLoc(result, min_val, max_val, minLoc, maxLoc, null); //the last null it's for optional mask mat()

    CvPoint point = new CvPoint();
    point.x(minLoc.x()+template.width());
    point.y(minLoc.y()+template.height());

    cvRectangle(img, minLoc, point, CvScalar.WHITE, 2, 8, 0); //Draw the rectangle result in original img.       
    cvShowImage("Image", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    //Release 
    cvReleaseImage(img);
    cvReleaseImage(template);
    cvReleaseImage(result);
```

I got the desired result but could not find a way of comparing two and more images with a template.
I converted the result image that is obtained to a matrix using asCvMat and got the matrix of probability of match on every pixel of original image.
I came across the determinant function in OpenCv to compare the two matrices to understand which of the images is a closer match to the template but could not find a corresponding function in JavaCv.

Is there any way by which I could compare the results and determine that which image is a closer match. I did come across ObjectFinder but could not find proper documentation of how to use it.

Please point out certain links or examples which may help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare image matching results by compering the max_val
I would even change the method to CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED and then you can set a threshold for max_val that is somewhere between 0 to 1.